# How to truncate text with a fade effect in Android?

Tags: android, textview, truncate

I am aware that this question has been asked before but the accepted answer does not work, and none of the comments are helping me. [How to replace ellipses with fade / fading edge in textview in Android sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7489068/how-to-replace-ellipses-with-fade-fading-edge-in-textview-in-android-sdk)

I am trying to use ellipsize="marquee" in order to truncate my text at the end and have a fade effect rather than an ellipsis.

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="200dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="LOREM IPSUM SCARAMOUCHE SCRARAMOUCHE GALILEO PACCIORETTY"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

I wish I could post a screenshot but SE wont't let me. here is what it looks like on screen

> LOREM IPSUM SCARAMOUC..

the word is not fading out, and it is not displaying an ellipsis either. instead it displays 2 dots.

note that I do not want the text to scroll, I just want it to truncate with a fade effect rather than an ellipsis.

Comment: `marquee` is scrolling, `end` for truncating at end

Comment: how to truncate at the end with a fade effect then?

Comment: @iamverysmart Did you find a solution to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdgeLength="@dimen/align_twenty"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:ellipsize="none"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also do this programmatically:

```
TextView yourTextView = findViewById(R.id.your_textview);    
yourTextView.setSingleLine(true);
yourTextView.setEllipsize();
yourTextView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
yourTextView.setFadingEdgeLength(20);
yourTextView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```